# Question about custom header in React Navigation v5 (Not clickable back button)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Hi I am using React navigation v5.
I am trying to implement custom header for specific screen. So my custom header looks like this

CustomHeader.js

```
export function CustomHeader({props}) {
  const {scene, previous, navigation} = props;
  const opacity = scene.route.params.opacity;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.headerStyle, {opacity}]}>
        <View style={styles.influencerNameContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.influencerName}>
            {scene.route.params.influencer.user.name}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </Animated.View>

      {previous ? (
/* This is a back button */
        <Button
          style={[styles.iconButton, {left: 0}]}
          icon={BackIcon}
          onPress={() => {navigation.goBack}
        />
      ) : (
        undefined
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Navigator looks like this

```
export function HomeStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      headerMode="screen"
      style={{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>

      <Stack.Screen
        name="InfluencerScreen"
        component={InfluencerScreen}
        options={{
          header: props => <CustomHeader props={props} />,
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

It renders custom headers and custom back button but back button is not clickable.
So I tried.

```
<Stack.Screen
        name="InfluencerScreen"
        component={InfluencerScreen}
        options={{
          header: props => <CustomHeader props={props} />,
          headerLeft: () => (
            <Button title="Back Button" onPress={() => alert('Pressed')} />
          )
        }}
      />
```

With this code, it doesn't show back button at all with custom header. But it shows custom back button when I remove custom header(header: props => ).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're destructuring `props` twice.. Try:

```js
export function CustomHeader({scene, previous, navigation}) {

  // const {scene, previous, navigation} = props; // remove this

  ...

}
```

**Edit:**

Also [goBack](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/#going-back) is a method so call it with **parentheses**:

```js
onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} // remove unnecessary `curly braces`
```

Answer (score 0):

You're showing a custom header, how you render the button is up-to you. React Navigation cannot show a back button since React Navigation is no longer rendering the header.

Instead of using `headerLeft` option, you need to put the back button inside your custom header.

Also your destructuring is incorrect. `function CustomHeader({props})` should be `function CustomHeader(props)` (without the curly braces).